# What are all the $k$-dimensional unimodular subspaces of $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove the following assertion:
**The set of subgroups of $(S^1)^n$ which are isomorphic by an element of $\operatorname{Aut}((S^1)^n)$ to the standard copy $(S^1)^k$ is naturally parametrized by the set of $k$-dimensional unimodular subspaces of $\mathbb{Z}^n$.**

By a $k$-*dimensional unimodular subspace* of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ we mean a rank $k$ submodule which is a direct summand.

> My guess is that the $k$-dimensional unimodular subspaces of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ would be those that are isomorphic by an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ to the standard copy of $\mathbb{Z}^k$. Is that correct?

In that case, since $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^n)\cong GL(n,\mathbb{Z})\cong\operatorname{Aut}((S^1)^n)$ I thought I could do the following:

Given any subgroup $H$ of $(S^1)^n$, as in the stated assertion, there is an $f \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $f(\mathbb{(S^1)^k}) = H$. So I can send this subgroup to $f(\mathbb{Z}^k)$. But this map need not be well defined. So what do I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rank $k$ (free) submodule $F$ of $\mathbb Z^n$ is obtained from a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb Z^n$ and a sequence $d_1\mid\cdots\mid d_k$ of positive integers. If you want $F$ to be a direct summand, then $\mathbb Z^n/F$ is free (since any submodule of $\mathbb Z^n$ is free). But $$\mathbb Z^n/F\simeq\mathbb Z/d_1\mathbb Z\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb Z/d_k\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z^{n-k},$$ so we must have $d_1=\cdots=d_k=1$, that is, $\{e_1,\dots,e_k\}$ is a basis of $F$. This shows that your guess is correct.